# HDD Beeping every 4 seconds

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Western Digital drive (https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-purple-sata-hdd#WD10PURZ). When I plug the SATA power into the drive, it begins beeping a half-second long tone every four seconds. There's no clicking at all, but the beeping makes the drive vibrate slightly. No damaged pins, motherboard is intact, haven't looked inside yet. I really hope this is fixable, because I cannot send this back in for a refund at the moment. Thank you!

Comment: Backup your data immediately, prepare for a full loss of the drive. The "beeping" indicates a mechanical failure, not because there is a speaker built in, but because something is going horribly wrong internally.

Comment: Last time I checked WD offered a 5 year warranty, at least here in Europe. You just had to register a warranty claim, enter date of purchase and send the drive. No other questions asked.

Answer (score 1):

Hard drives do not have speakers. If you're certain the drive is where the sound is coming from, that sound is being produced by parts that aren't supposed to be making noise, making noise. This is probably because parts are rubbing where they aren't supposed to be.

This is really, really bad for a drive, and any data you've got on that drive is at risk of being completely gone at any moment, and that is not hyperbole.

Comment: Just bought it, it did this straight out of the box. Guess there's nothing I can do, which sucks, because it was a lot of money.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You can replace it if it's new. If the retailer doesn't want to make it right, the manufacturer will have an RMA process that will have you covered. Frustrating? Yea. Lost money? Shouldn't be.